# JavaScript: can't replace element in NodeList

Tags: javascript, bubble-sort, nodelist

This is part of a Bubble Sort to sort two parallel NodeLists, `payRates` and `txlis`.

```
for(var index=0; index < payRates.length; index++){
    if(payRates[index] < payRates[index+1]){
        var temp = payRates[index];
        payRates[index] = payRates[index+1];
        payRates[index+1] = temp;

        temp = txlis[index];
        txlis[index] = txlis[index+1];
        txlis[index+1] = temp;
        bubbled = true;
}
```

`payRates` is a NodeList of floating point objects. `txlis` is a NodeList of LI elements. I can overwrite elements in `payRates` but no matter what I try, the elements in `txlis` remain in their original order.

I've tried it like this example, I've tried `list.parentNode.replaceChild()` (where `list` is a UL element from which `txlis` is derived), I've tried creating new LI elements from scratch, but nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's a NodeList of floating point objects? AFAIK NodeLists are colletions of DOM nodes. And that's probably why you can't sort them (try to `slice` them into arrays first, then sort the arrays).

Comment: The slice method mentioned by @bfavaretto is `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList);`, which will give you an _Array_ which you can now work with.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. `payRates` is a NodeList of SPANs. I'll try `slice`, thanks.